# Confirmation of Equivalent Form of Riemann Hypothesis

Tags: logarithms, gcd-and-lcm, riemann-hypothesis, open-problem

Can anyone, who has knowledge of the following, share some more details about it because not much information is available publicly regarding the same:

RH is equivalent to the assertion that for all $n\ge3$ $$| \log \operatorname{lcm}(1,2,\dots, n) - n | < \sqrt{n}\log^2(n)$$
where $\operatorname{lcm}$ denotes the least common multiple.

Moreover, I also want to confirm if this equivalent problem is correct and if yes, where we can find the proof of this equivalence?

The only article we can find publicly is the "Prime Number Races" written by Granville and Martin who mention this equivalence on Page Number 9 of their article as:

Riemann’s prediction has been made more precise over the years, and it can now be expressed very explicitly as:

$$| \ln \operatorname{lcm}(1,2,\dots, x) - x | ≤ 2\sqrt{x}\ln^2(x)$$
when x ≥ 100.

In fact, this inequality is equivalent to the celebrated Riemann Hypothesis, perhaps the most prominent open problem in mathematics.

**Sources:**
[1]: http://oeis.org/A003418
[2]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function
[3]: [https://dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/PDF/PrimeRace.pdf](https://dms.umontreal.ca/%7Eandrew/PDF/PrimeRace.pdf)
[4]: https://mathoverflow.net/q/232413

Comment: It is equivalent to ${\displaystyle \pi (x)=\operatorname {li} (x)+O\!\left({\sqrt {x}}\,\log x\right)}$, which is equivalent to RH. Granville and Martin refer to it by the footnote $7$ in the article [3].

Comment: Yes Sir, I am aware of that footnote and went through it too. However, I still did not understand how it was derived and how the equivalence was proved. That's why I decided to ask this question. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I agree with you that it would've been nice if Granville and that other folk included a reference :)

As you know, $\ln\mathop{\rm lcm}(1,2,\dots,x)$ is the same as the [Chebyshev function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function) $\psi(x)$. The [Riemann hypothesis Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis#Distribution_of_prime_numbers) contains the assertion that RH implies
$$
|\psi(x)-x| < \frac1{8\pi} \sqrt x \ln^2 x \quad\text{for all } x\ge 73.2
$$
(which is stronger than the inequality in the OP)
and gives this attribution: L. Schoenfeld, *Sharper bounds for the Chebyshev functions θ(x) and ψ(x). II*, Mathematics of Computation **30** (1976), 337–360.

For the reverse implication, it is known that any inequality of the form $|\psi(x)-x| < Cx^\theta$ for $x$ sufficiently large implies that $\zeta(s)$ has no zeros with real part greater than $\theta$. (This is a consequence of "Landau's theorem", and a version can be found, for example, as Theorem 15.2 in Montgomery and Vaughan's *Multiplicative Number Theory I. Classical Theory*.) In particular, $|\psi(x)-x| < \frac1{8\pi} \sqrt x \ln^2 x$ implies $|\psi(x)-x| < Cx^{1/2+\varepsilon}$ for any $\varepsilon>0$ when $x$ is sufficiently large, and thus $\zeta(s)$ has no zeros with real part exceeding $\frac12+\varepsilon$ for every $\varepsilon>0$, which implies the Riemann hypothesis.

Comment: Thank you very much @Greg Martin. I have few more questions:

1. By now we have total of 3 equivalent problems of the RH i.e. one that I originally mentioned in my question, second one appears in the "Prime Number Races" article, and third (stronger) one that you mentioned which involves the Chebyshev function.

I want to know which is the original one and best one among the three? And assuming that the first two forms are weaker versions of the stronger version having Chebyshev function, are they entirely correct or not?

Comment: 2. Also is it worth working on the weaker ones or should we focus only on the stronger one?
3. Although I am aware of the Chebyshev functions and Landau's theorem, yet I want to know if there is some upper bound for the Chebyshev function, because it makes the task of proving (or disproving) this equivalent problem much easier.

Kindly spare some time to answer these additional questions and doubts (which I believe that most of the public also has) and I am accepting your answer too. Thanks again for the explanation and references.

Comment: BTW you mentioned that - The Riemann hypothesis Wikipedia page contains the assertion that RH *implies* the stronger inequality than the inequality I gave in the OP. But the question is, is RH *equivalent* to that inequality?

Comment: While it might not be immediately clear, all of these questions are already answered in my post. RH implies the strongest inequality (and thus it implies the two weaker inequalities as well), while the second paragraph of my post describes why the strongest inequality (indeed, any of the inequalities) implies RH. Therefore RH is equivalent to any/all those inequalities.

Comment: Thank you. Just one final clarification required:
In the RHS of all these inequalities we can find $\log^2(n)$. But what does it exactly mean in this context?
Does it denote log(n) * log(n) or log(log(n)) or something else entirely?

Comment: $\log^2 n$ means $(\log n)^2$ or $(\log n)\times(\log n)$

Comment: Understood, thank you. You helped me (and others too) greatly.